# Mysterious bytes in GZIP (bytestream) compression Python3

Tags: python-3.x, compression, gzip, zlib

I have a file that contains lots of contents (symbol heavy `<>?!""''=:;`), I wish to compress in parts, I read the file, convert to a bytestream and then compress. I'd expect the compression to come out vaguely like:
`\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x92\x04` and so on.

However, it comes out more like:
`\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\xa60v?\x04{?X\x0eDa` and so on. Surely I should be getting hex values within the range 00 to ff?

Main snippet of `Python3` code:

```
with open('somefile', 'r') as f:
  for lines in f.readlines():
    messages = (str(lines)).encode('ascii') #Or 'UTF-8' both produce funny results
    compMessages = gzip.compress(messages) #Default level of 6 is fine here
    return compMessages
```

The only interesting/relevant information I can find is that
`len(str(lines))` is a different value to `len(lines.encode('ascii'))`

Ideas please?

Comment: Huh?  What is it you're expecting?  A compressed stream should be expected to use all possible byte values, so I have no idea what you mean by "mysterious" bytes.

Comment: I'm expecting 'pure hex'. That's to say values between \x00 and \xff. Not values like `\xfaXg}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "mysterious" about your output. You're just not reading it correctly. This:

```
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\xa60v?\x04{?X\x0eDa
```

is the same as

```
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\xa6\x30\x76\x3f\x04\x7b\x3f\x58\x0e\x44\x61
```

It's just that the ASCII-printable characters (the ones with hex values between `0x20` and `0x7E`), such as `0`, `v`, `?`, `{`, `D`, and `a`, are shown as their ascii values, rather than as `\x` escape codes.

To verify this, observe the following:

```
>>> [ord(i) for i in '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\xa60v?\x04{?X\x0eDa']
[31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 166, 48, 118, 63, 4, 123, 63, 88, 14, 68, 97]
```

All of the values are between `0` and `255`.